# Navigate to a component without changing url in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to navigate from one component to another ,as in, upon a button click in component1 , we should be redirected to component2 without having to use this.navigation.navigate() as this requires specifying a new URL. I want the URL to remain same and I do not want to use react-router. Is there a way to do this?

The behavior ideally is that a button click in component1 will render component2 in the place of component1 which takes up the whole screen. In a way component1 would cause component2 to render. But I do not want the user to have access to component2 directly. Hence I do not want a change in the URL. Would containers still be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return that component witch appropriate by your condition like this:

```js
class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    let cond = this.props.condition
    return (
      { cond ? <Component1/> : <Component2/> }
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT: switch may be like this:

```js
class Component1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onDone}/>
    )
  }
}


class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { done: false }
  }

  render() {
    let cond = this.state.done
    return (
      { cond ?
        <Component1 onDone={()=>this.setState({done:true})}/> :
        <Component2/>
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be a state variable of Container as I want to load Component2 only when there is a button click in component1? I will update the condition when the button is clicked. I assume that components are re-rendered only when state changes. So in this case for cond to be rechecked I need to make an update to this.state.condition

Comment: Yeah, I've added the example.

Comment: The button is a subcomponent of component1. So I will have to change the state of Component1 in the sub component and then expect this change to render component2 from the container. Is that too complicated as I am technically having a grandchild affect the grandparent's behaviour?

Comment: I will mark the answer right , the moment it's works for my problem. No worries.

Comment: There is no visible (and actually) states else except `Container.done` don't  warry about complicated relations. In this case relations graph have no loops and this is just event passing from child to parent and one more.