# Change routing for components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have tree components:

```
class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

class Task extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Task</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

class User extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>User</h2>
               // <Link to='/task'>???</Link>                
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

And I have index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/user' component={User} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

There are two components that are mapped to two URLs, how to make the third component render separately, when you click on something (button or link), so that the URL does not change. That is, another component was rendered, and the address remained the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this SO Post, I think it could help you out.

[Navigate to a component without changing url in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110593/navigate-to-a-component-without-changing-url-in-reactjs)

Comment: If there's anything wich is still unclear to you, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function that binds to the constructor and declare a state to determine whether to show your second page or not (true || false)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import MyComponent3 from './MyComponent3.jsx'

export default class MyComponent2 extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this)
    this.state = { show : false}
  }

  handleOnClick () {
    this.setState({show:true})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleOnClick()}>Submit Me</button>
        { this.state.show && <MyComponent3/> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```